# Add files to the app on the run

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if I could add the files to the app resources from an external url. As in suppose I see a url which has a nice image. Can I download that from the website and add it as a resource and use it locally for later use ? I am sure there is way But Need some guidance on how to approach the problem and The set of Classes that could be used with explanantion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can't change anything in your app bundle after it has been signed.  If you did, you'd make the signature invalid, and the iPhone would refuse to run your app.  Your best bet is to add the files to the Documents or tmp folder.  There really isn't much of a reason to have stuff in your own bundle - is there a reason you have to have those images there?